# An error preventing me from adding SQL server database to my project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Ok so I was creating a website project in Visual Studio 2013, and i kept working on it perfectly for one whole month. When I wanted to add a SQL database and use it with a form i kept getting an error regarding the port or something when I try to run the page. After that, I deleted VS2013 and downloaded VSCommunity " which is VS2015 I believe " to check if I will get the same error again and to update the software.

Now when I try to add a SQL server database to my project I keep getting an error preventing me from adding the database to the project. This is the error that I keep getting:

[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SISdV.jpg)

I checked in the internet for a solution and nothing worked even after trying all of the solutions. I tried enabling the TCP/IP from the sql server 2008 configuration manager, enabling the named pipes, and even re-installed VS2015.
I cant really understand where is the problem !! I just deleted the old software and downloaded a new version!!

have been trying to solve this issue for 2 days without any progress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be VS. Judging from the error message alone, your SQL Server service isn't running and should be started.

EDIT: In line with rajeshmpanchal's "suggestion", here's an excerpt from the MSDN's page on managing your SQL Server.

> To start, stop, pause, resume, or restart the an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine
>   On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2016, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>   If the User Account Control dialog box appears, click Yes.
>   In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, click SQL Server Services.
>   In the results pane, right-click SQL Server (MSSQLServer) or a named instance, and then click Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, or Restart.
>   Click OK to close SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx) to the page

Comment: this cannot be the answer.

Comment: Why not, rajeshmpanchal?

Comment: we should guide him with some steps to resolve the issue. Not by just judging.

Comment: Good, this might can help to him and others too... Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the downvote. Unfortunately, that doesn't work with comments

Comment: Thank you for the comment Franco but when I on SQL server services I get this message " sql server 2008 the remote procedure call failed "

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting VS2015 and SQL server 2008 and installed VS2015 again with SQl Server 2014 express and the problem is solved now.

No idea what was the problem.